# Is there any way to get sum of data while search on particular searchbox of in thead in jQuery dataTable

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am working on ERP project where i want show only table data sum total after some individual column search in this.
there is one table which contains some calculated field , i want 'gwt' column total as i search on seachbox some value like 2.58 ,this value has 4 entry so i get only searchable value sum total in result

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#table tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + ' Search" />');
  });
  // DataTable
  var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    searching: true,
    dom: 't',
    colReorder: true,
    initComplete: function() {
      //apply the search
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var that = this;
        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function() {
          if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that
             .search(this.value)
             .draw();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('thead th').each(function(i) {
    calculateColumn(i);
  });
});

function calculateColumn(index) {
  var total = 0;
  $('table  tr').each(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($('td', this).eq(index).text());
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      total += value;
    }
  });
  $('tbody tr').eq(index).text(' ' + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

[image]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and libraries to make a [mcve]

Comment: in html part it only contains table tag